# How to make a function with event DRY?

Tags: javascript, function, events, dry

I'm having a bit of a problem here. I'm using the same function with two series of buttons, but I have to make two seperate functions because of the event in it.

```
const switchButtonSite = (e) => {
  siteBtn.forEach(button => {
    if(e.target === button) {
      button.classList.remove("not-active")
      button.classList.add("active")
    } else {
      button.classList.remove("active")
      button.classList.add("not-active")
    }
  })
}

const switchButtonGit = (e) => {
  gitClientBtn.forEach(button => {
    if(e.target === button) {
      button.classList.remove("not-active")
      button.classList.add("active")
    } else {
      button.classList.remove("active")
      button.classList.add("not-active")
    }
  })
}
```

Is there a way make one function out of these, so I can use it looking something like this:

```
switchButton(siteBtn)
switchButton(gitClientBtn)
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML, please?

Comment: `const switchButtonSite = (e) => dryFunction(e, siteBtn);` - I'm sure you can figure out what `dryFunction` would look like

Comment: @JaromandaX Thank you, I figured it out!